# Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: instruction expected an executable account

Tags: solana-test-validator

Is this happening because the metadata program is not available in test validators?

Logs:

```
Streaming transaction logs mentioning GnJ3zD973kcYKpcJ5Zsysbm3WUmv6sMDxTsKU7Hdx8tK. Confirmed commitment
Transaction executed in slot 3868:
  Signature: 2LRWUrtF74V8cUwqGuPT1Lx3hKqNG3miAx5tMBKwgmCpygry7YiAygtNNjNSLZMQMFk2LJxyVVZjBtitJGoxMKz5
  Status: Ok
  Log Messages:
    Program GnJ3zD973kcYKpcJ5Zsysbm3WUmv6sMDxTsKU7Hdx8tK invoke [1]
    Program log: Instruction: CreateProfile
    Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]
    Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success
    Program GnJ3zD973kcYKpcJ5Zsysbm3WUmv6sMDxTsKU7Hdx8tK consumed 8026 of 200000 compute units
    Program GnJ3zD973kcYKpcJ5Zsysbm3WUmv6sMDxTsKU7Hdx8tK success
Transaction executed in slot 3869:
  Signature: 26SCwRzBwPmGMwjaSoyYd64nLqzERtg1qqQgMLV99QRkHzroBsV2Ldztn4xYpKrEjxg3fHxKyYv3nwr9XKCEneok
  Status: Ok
  Log Messages:
    Program GnJ3zD973kcYKpcJ5Zsysbm3WUmv6sMDxTsKU7Hdx8tK invoke [1]
    Program log: Instruction: UpdateKyc
    Program GnJ3zD973kcYKpcJ5Zsysbm3WUmv6sMDxTsKU7Hdx8tK consumed 4158 of 200000 compute units
    Program GnJ3zD973kcYKpcJ5Zsysbm3WUmv6sMDxTsKU7Hdx8tK success
Transaction executed in slot 3870:
  Signature: 4WkuJ4WjcrX11Bpoa25JHb6wFycczevyTwHhghzoz19esST3Un2cCUuoMHLjLRRTURL7CjcW7pbNVoeJEiWGqah7
  Status: Ok
  Log Messages:
    Program GnJ3zD973kcYKpcJ5Zsysbm3WUmv6sMDxTsKU7Hdx8tK invoke [1]
    Program log: Instruction: UpdateKyc
    Program GnJ3zD973kcYKpcJ5Zsysbm3WUmv6sMDxTsKU7Hdx8tK consumed 5081 of 200000 compute units
    Program GnJ3zD973kcYKpcJ5Zsysbm3WUmv6sMDxTsKU7Hdx8tK success
```

Error message:

```
  1) Collections
       Initiates the program:
     Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: instruction expected an executable account
      at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4480:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4439:20)
      at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:288:21)
      at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:148:14)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)
```

This is the instruction that is causing the AccountNotExecutable error:

````
        msg!("Creating metadata account {}", ctx.accounts.metadata.key());
        invoke(
            &create_metadata_accounts_v3(
                TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
                ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
                ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
                "name".to_string(),
                "symbol".to_string(),
                "uri".to_string(),
                None,
                1,
                true,
                true,
                None,
                None,
                None,
            ),
            &[
                ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info()
            ],
        )?;```
````

Comment: If you could try to send the transaction with the option `skipPreflight: true` then the program logs should contain a more verbose error than what the transaction simulator returns. At first glance though, the error does seem to indicate you passed in a regular account where it expected a program account / executable account

Comment: Hi thank you for your help! Ran the rpc with the flag and got this output: `Error: Raw transaction 4pEgKNhWb6u1jTht56drSf6YzZHDMyedBAXHCLaVKJUJ9QVPQN7LU5EEDUGAdg29dxnrdrQeFjGBShtNu848schh failed ({"err":{"InstructionError":[0,"AccountNotExecutable"]}})`

Comment: So exactly what you said, but I'm trying to fio which account it's talking about.

Comment: If anchor isn't telling you exactly which account is not executable, i would just go through each account one by one and print out the account info of them in the client until you figure out which one is not executable but should be according to the program

Comment: by "test validators" you mean `solana-test-validator`?

Answer (score 1):

There are two points here:

1. Vanila test local validator that ships with solana sdk tools doesn't have metaplex metadata token program. One should clone https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js and run `yarn && yarn build && yarn amman:start` to have local validator with loaded programs.
2. Make sure token_metadata_program is not marked as mutable.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a simple solution:

**Step1**: dump the target program to .so file from devnet, testnet or mainnet

```
solana program dump -u m metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s tests/metaplex_token_metadata_program.so
```

where `-u m` is dump from mainnet. The output file is `tests/metaplex_token_metadata_program.so`. You can custom for your use

**Step2**: add config to Anchor.toml

```
[[test.genesis]]
address = "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"  
program = "tests/metaplex_token_metadata_program.so"
```

where `program` is .so file you dumped before, `address` is address of program in localnet

**Step3**: run `anchor test` and enjoy.